# Conditional convergence, Mertens theorem

Tags: real-analysis

If $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ both converge and one of them absolutely then the Cauchy product $\sum c_n$ converges to $\sum a_n \sum b_n$. ($c_n = \sum_{k = 0}^n a_k b_{n - k}$), by Mertens Theorem.

Now, if both converge conditionally then the product does not have to converge as $a_n = b_n = (-1)^n/n$ shows.
My question now is: What if $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ both converge conditionally and $\sum c_n$ converges, then is it always true that $\sum c_n$ converges to the product?

By the way, this is not homework, I'm already past the real analysis part.

Comment: It is [known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product#Cesàro's_theorem) that the Cauchy product is Cesàro summable to $\sum a_n \sum b_n$. If $\sum c_n$ is convergent then its value equals the Cesàro sum.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This follows readily from Abel's convergence theorem: if $\sum_0^\infty a_n$
converges then
$$\sum_0^\infty a_n=\lim_{x\to1^-}\sum_0^\infty a_n x^n.$$